# Lenovo IdeaPad 5 15IIL05 Maximum RAM

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, memory, lenovo-laptop

The time has come for me to upgrade my memory since 8GB won't suffice certain virtualization needs. Now, I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed and I ran the:

```
sudo dmidecode -t 16
```

code to check the supported capacity. And these are the results:

```
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.2 present.

Handle 0x0027, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 8 GB
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Number Of Devices: 2
```

8GB max? What the...? Okay, so this was confusing. It has two slots of 4GB, and it tells me that that is the max supported sum. Weird, so I go and check the official specs from *Lenovo* , and this is what it says (page 2 of the PDF):

[image: Screenshot of the Lenovo System Specs].

Footnote, the ** is: • Feature with ** means that only one offering listed under the feature is configured on selected models.

Okay...I am not a smart man, and this confuses me. The footnote[1] clearly says that it *could* be "supported", but then again, on every model it ends with *"Not upgradable"*. So, does it mean that it cannot be because they don't want me to open up the machine, or that they somehow disabled it on the BIOS level or whatever? I've never encountered an issue like this, and I am really not sure. And of course, I don't want to spend my money on a new 16GB card only to find out that it doesn't and won't work.

Oh, and one more thing. It says *"Memory soldered to motherboard"*, and I am afraid to ask before I even try to pry it open, does that mean what I think it means? That it's not the classic pin-slot but literally soldered like they solder integrated GPU's, N-S bridges etc.?

Comment: The footnote says nothing of what you think it does, it's just your assumption. Besides that note is likely to be generic for all models with or without upgradable RAM. And yes, soldered RAM modules is a thing.

Comment: Edited my "assumption", thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soldered memory is not your problem. There are notebooks with both soldered memory and slots.

**The problem is “no slots”. That means no upgrading.**

And indeed Notebookcheck has [a review of this notebook](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Lenovo-IdeaPad-5-15IIL05-Review-Good-performance-and-a-long-battery-life-thanks-to-the-70-Wh-battery.480460.0.html) with an image of the interior. There are no memory slots.

Comment: Wow, your answer is perfect. The review is really...well detailed. Will use it for future references. Thank you so much. And, *sigh*, I am stuck with 8GB, that's a real bummer. Oh well, you live and learn I guess.